# AJAX, with node js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I would like to learn how to work with AJAX, let's say I want to connect to a node.js server, from my html page. The page has one button, when pressing that we send a request to the server, the server sends back a 'hello world' string.

I have learned how to make a html5 page, and how to start a node.js server

A simple node.js server

```
    var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Hello World\n');
    }).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

This prints hello world, that's all good.

But, How can I make it so that when I press a button on a html page, a function is called, that 'connects' or 'calls' the server, and gets a string in return?
I have a book on Node.js, but it says nothing about AJAX, is there a better way to do it?

I'd be glad for some help!

Comment: Ajax just means "Making an HTTP request and processing the response from JS". How you produce that server side response is beside the point, so you can produce it the same way as you produce any other response. Just use any Ajax tutorial.

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

`AJAX` call needs to be initiated from the client i.e. browser.
Your `node.js` application than receives a request, handles it and returns response back to client

using jQuery it would look like this:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: Can you take a look at this? Why is it not working?

Comment: ... can't place code here..