# How do I use AJAX within a web simulation, XAMPP

Tags: javascript, ajax, xampp

I'm totally new to Ajax but want to learn how to use it. I've read the "getting started" section provided by Mozilla and I'm following that but it fails to open a function on onreadystatechange.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action=""> 
            Other info: <textarea cols=50 rows=10 
                                  onblur = "processText(this.value)"
                                  id='info1'></textarea>"
        </form>

        <script>
            function processText(str) {
                var xhttp;
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                alert('After new XMLHttpRequest');
                alert('ready state 1' + xhttp.readyState);
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    alert('onready statechange function entered');
                };

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've reduced this to the minimum to show the problem. When I run this I enter some text in the box then move the cursor outside, 'onblur'. This correctly calls function 'processText(str)' and the alert 'After new XMLHttpRequest' is shown. The next alert shows ReadyState = 10 (I thought only zero through 4 were possible!). The alert 'onready statechange function entered' does not show.

I saw infoermation on stackoverflow at
[How to make AJAX work on local server using XAMPP or node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273738/how-to-make-ajax-work-on-local-server-using-xampp-or-node-js)

it mentions that the port may need to be set. I am using port 1337 so I get the XAMPP page via 'localhost:1337'. However I cannot find how to set the port, if that is the problem.

Here is my configuration:
XAMPP version 3.2.2
Netbeans 8.1
Internet Explorer 11

Comment: "_I thought only zero through 4 were possible!_" It is. The `1` of your `10` is part of the `'ready state 1'` string.

Comment: You're not *sending* the Ajax call with `xhttp.send()`. You're just creating the object and doing nothing with it

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax request needs open and send methods. Adding these lines to your example, you actually does the ajax request.

```
function processText(str) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  alert('After new XMLHttpRequest');
  alert('ready state 1' + xhttp.readyState);
  xhttp.open('get', 'http://your.url/path:port'); // <- new
  // -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    alert('onready statechange function entered');
  };
  xhttp.open(null); // <- new
  // -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you. I was being stupid when I interpreted the ready state as 10, thanks for spotting this. Robin - your answer pointed out my ignorance. I did have an xhttp.open('GET', ...) call in my original script but I thought the error was occurring before this so I pared it back before sending. I had originally used a url with just the file name and without "http://localhost:1337/   ". Now I get a ready state of 1 so I'm making progress and feel sure I can work from here. Thanks very much for your help.